# How do I robustly compare phone numbers in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

In an Android app I am developing, I have a database which maps:

> <Contact ID, Contact Lookup Key> --> <**My Custom Data Associated with Contact**>

When an incoming SMS message comes in, I want to be able to look up **My Custom Data Associated with Contact** associated with the contact who sent the SMS message. I want to do the lookup in as few steps as possible.

The only data I can get out of the SMS message is the **Phone Number**, so the problem is basically one of mapping the **Phone Number** to **My Custom Data Associated with Contact** in as few steps as possible.

Now, I am aware that I can look up a contact from a phone number up using [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729551/contactscontract-lookup-phone-number-by-contact-id). However, this does not get me to my desired result because both the Contact ID and Contact Lookup Key are subject to change. So if either the ID or the Lookup Key has changed for any contact I have persisted to my database, I have to basically load my whole database and refresh the ID/Lookup Key for each row before I can test whether they represent the same contact as the one returned by ContactsContract.PhoneLookup. This is a pretty brutal solution which I would prefer to avoid.

What I would like to do is keep a table mapping phone numbers to my custom data (in an N:1 relationship).

> <Phone Number> --> <**My Custom Data Associated with Contact**>

This way, in theory at least, I can index the phone number column and just look up the data in one step. However, phone numbers come in many formats. My solution will only work if I can create a canonical representation of a given phone number. My plan was to use [PhoneNumberUtils.getStrippedReversed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#getStrippedReversed(java.lang.String)) to produce an efficiently indexable canonical phone number, but this fails on a trivial case, for example:

> PhoneNumberUtils.getStrippedReversed("+1(306)6656320") --> 02365566031
>   PhoneNumberUtils.getStrippedReversed("(306)6656320") --> 0236556603

They aren't the same number!

So with that by way of long-winded explanation, my question is: *Can anyone think of a way of converting a phone number to a canonical phone number so that I can perform an indexed database lookup on the number*, or any other solution to the problem I described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method along with getStrippedReversed

```
public static String toCallerIDMinMatch (String phoneNumber)
```

***Returns the rightmost MIN_MATCH (5) characters in the network portion in *reversed* order This can be used to do a database lookup against the column that stores getStrippedReversed() Returns null if phoneNumber == null***

Then your comparison will give you the desired result